# Give algorithm for finding bidiagonal matrix similar to triangular matrix

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

> Is there an algorithm that takes an [upper triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) matrix $T$ over the complex numbers as input, and outputs a [bidiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidiagonal_matrix) $B$ which $T$ is similar to?
>
> We may assume that $T$ is invertible.

#### Remarks

By $T$ being similar to $B$, I mean that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $B = PTP^{-1}$.

Such a matrix certainly exists: For instance, $B$ could be the Jordan form of $T$.

**Don't misunderstand my question!** The usual "bidiagonalisation" algorithms (which occur in the context of computing SVD for instance) don't preserve eigenvalues. They only preserve the singular values, which is not what I want.

There are probably multiple algorithms for producing this. I think some might have issues with numerical stability.

Comment: The Jordan shape is bi-diagonal and any matrix can be put on Jordan form. You are right that many algorithms exist for this, as a quick internet search will show. So what is the remaining question?

Comment: @JosBergervoet Those algorithms are numerically unstable, as I pointed out.

Comment: Their runtime is also $\Omega(n^4)$ I think